# Fully abstract Lie theory?

Tags: book-recommendation

I have for a while been sniffing around the edges of Lie groups, -algebras etc, but what tends to put me off is that it always seems to focus on matrix groups and detailed calculations of things, like $exp()$, that I feel ought to have a more general, abstract definition. Thus:

- Is there a book/books that treat Lie theory in full abstraction - perhaps even from Category theory?

Comment: For what it's worth, $\exp$ is a generic construction taking a vector from a tangent space on a manifold to a point in a neighborhood.

Comment: @lisyarus: there is no such construction on a *manifold*. $\exp$ can be defined on a Riemannian manifold, and that definition does not (immediately) specialize to the exponential map on a Lie group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want abstract Lie theory there's plenty of abstract Lie theory to go around. You can consult, for example, Serre's *[Lie Algebras and Lie Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-70634-2)* which IIRC does not even restrict to working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ in case you want to study $p$-adic Lie groups or similar! Fulton and Harris' *[Representation Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387974954)* is a more pleasant read; they focus a lot on examples which I think is healthy but you will find general definitions and proofs about the exponential map etc. as well. I also hear good things about Knapp's *[Lie Groups: Beyond an Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817642595)* although as stated in the title it's not an introductory text.